# How to use context is a react class that is not a component

Tags: reactjs, use-context

In my app I have a class that works with a server (sends and receives data). I need to pass to this class a token. I have a context that holds it. But I can't find a way to send it to my class.

This is a Context:

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from 'react';
import loginService from '../service/LoginService';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

const AuthContextProvider = (props) => {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
    const [userToken, setUserToken] = useState("");
    const [userId, setUserId] = useState("");
    const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");

    const toggleAuth = () => {
        if (!isAuthenticated) {
            setUserToken(loginService.getUserToken());
            setUserId(loginService.getUserId());
            setUserName(loginService.getUserName());
            console.log("The user id: " + userId);
            setIsAuthenticated(true);
        } else {
            setUserToken(null);
            setUserId(null);
            setUserName(null);
            setIsAuthenticated(false);
        }

    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ isAuthenticated, toggleAuth }}>
            {props.children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

And this is how I try to use the context in my class:

```
class MediaService {
    static contextType = AuthContext;
    galleryItems = [];

    constructor() {
        this.galleryItems = [];
    }

    addItem = (item) => {
        axios.post("http://localhost:8080/image", item, {
            headers: {
                "Authorization": `Barier ${**this.context.userToken**}`
            }
        })
            .then((response) => {
                item.id = response.data.id;
                this.galleryItems.push(item);
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
    }
}
```

But I get an error that this.context is undefined. How can I change my code to overcome this?

I know about useContext, but when I try to switch to the function I get another error that useContext can be used only in components, but this is not a component.

And I want to keep the database logic in a separate class, not in any component at all.

Comment: By showing how you're using the `MediaService` class in your app, we can make a better suggestion to you. My first question is "why is this a class at all?" and I think seeing how you use it would help.

Comment: I use it like this:

import mediaService from "../share/service/MediaService"
import { AddImageForm } from "../share/ui/AddImageForm";

export function AddImagePage(props) {
    const onAddImage = (newImage) => {
        mediaService.addItem(newImage);
        props.history.push("/");
    }

    return (
        <AddImageForm addItem={onAddImage} ></AddImageForm>
    )
}

Comment: `.then()`  called out of what? don't see. should be `window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_requestAccounts' }).then((result,conngoes)=>{window.accountf = result; setConngoes(!false);})`

Comment: and if it works with `this.` it should work without